# Why "IN " query tag is so costly in SQL stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I improve my performance issue? I have an SQL query with 'IN' I guess 'IN'  making some costly performance issue. Do I need an index for my SQL query?

My query:

```sql
SELECT [p].[ReferencedxxxId]  
FROM [Common].[xxxReference] AS [p]  
WHERE ([p].[IsDeleted] = 0)  
  AND (([p].[ReferencedxyzType] = @__refxyzType_0)
  AND [p].[ReferencedxxxId] IN ('42342','ffsdfd','5345345345'))
```

My solution: which one is correct, clustered or non-clustered index?

```sql
USE [xxx]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NonClusteredIndexDemo_xxxId
ON [Common].[xxxReference](xxxId)
INCLUDE ([ID],[ReferencedxxxId])
WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON, ONLINE=ON, FILLFACTOR=90)
GO
```

Second:

```sql
CREATE INDEX xxxReference_ReferencedxxxId_index
ON [Common].[xxxReference]  (ReferencedxxxId)[/code]
```

Which one is correct, or is there a better solution?

Comment: `and exists (subquery)` sometimes performs better than `and column in ()` Have you tried that ?

Comment: you need an index on `ReferencedEntityId`

Comment: You need an index on `IsDeleted`, `ReferencedEntityType` and `ReferencedEntityId` - probably in this exact order.

Comment: Is your `ReferencedEntityId` really `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: From what I have seen, `IN` is expanded into a series of `OR` statements. So when you have a large number of values I have seen it cause problems. As @GuidoG suggested, have you tried `EXISTS` in a subquery? It's my understanding that the optimizer can use it as "short circuit" to avoid the full OR expansion of an IN query.

Comment: Check @ZoharPeled answer, he is right about the index. If you put the index he advised your query will go from index scan to index seek.

Comment: @Penguen . . . Your suggested index really has nothing to do with your query, so clustered or unclustered doesn't matter.  Your query doesn't even reference `EntityId`.

Comment: It's not the stored procedur, but your query.

Comment: Can you add the index definition (from the Index Scan operator in your query plan) to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. If you have a SELECT statement inside the IN, that should be avoided
   and should be replaced with an EXISTS clause. But in your above
   example, that is not relevant as you have direct values inside IN.

   Using EXISTS and NOT EXISTS instead of IN and NOT IN helps SQL
   Server to not needing to scan each value of the column for each
   values inside the IN / NOT IN and rather can short circuit the
   search once a match or non-match found.
2. Avoid the implicit conversion. They degrade the performance due to
   many reasons including i> SQL Server not able to find proper
   statistics on an index and hence not able to leverage an index and
   would rather go make use of a clustered index available in the table
   (which may not be covering your query), ii> Not assigning proper
   required RAM during memory allocation phase of the query by storage
   engine, iii> Cardinality estimation becomes wrong as SQL Server
   would not have statistics on the computed value of that column, and
   rather probably had statistics on that column.

   If you look at your execution plan posted above, you will see a
   yellow mark in your 'SELECT'. If you hover over it, you will see
   one/more warning messages. If your warning is related to implicit
   conversion, try to use proper datatypes during comparison.

   Eg. What is the datatype of the column '[ReferencedxxxId]'? If it
   is not an NVARCHAR and is rather a VARCHAR, then I would suggest:
3. Make the values inside the IN as VARCHAR (currently you are making them NVARCHAR). This way you will still be able to take full advantage of the rowstore index created on [ReferencedxxxId] column.
4. If you must have the values as NVARCHAR inside the IN clause, then you should:

   - CONVERT/CAST the column [ReferencedxxxId] in your IN clause. This is going to get rid of the Implicit conversion but you will no longer be able to take full advantage of the rowstore index on [ReferencedxxxId] column.

     +
   - Rather create a clustered/nonclustered columnstore index on the table covering the columns used in the query. This should significantly enhance the performance of your SELECT query.
5. If you decided to go with the route of using rowstore index by correcting the values inside the IN, you need to make sure that you create a clustered/nonclustered index which covers the query. Meaning the index covers the columns on which you are doing search ([ReferencedxxxId], [ReferencedxxxType], [IsDeleted]) and then including the columns used in SELECT statement under INCLUDE clause (if it is a nonclustered index)
6. Also, when you are creating a composite rowstore index, try to keep the order of columns inside the index high cardinality to low cardinality from left to right to make the best use of that index.

Answer (score 3):

The performance problem of this query is not the result of using the `IN` operator.
This operator performs very well with small lists (say, less than 1000 members).

The performance bottle neck here is the fact that SQL Server performs an index scan instead of an index seek (which is very costly), and the key lookup, which is 20% of the query cost.

To avoid both problems, you can add an index on `IsDeleted`, `ReferencedxyzType` and `ReferencedxxxId` - probably in this exact order.

SQL Performance tuning is a science that tends to look a little like art or magic - either way you look at it it requires a good knowledge of both the theory and practice of index settings and the relevant systems requirements.

Therefor, my suggestion is this: Do not attempt to solve it yourself with the help of strangers on the internet. Get an expert for a consulting job for a couple of hours/days to analyze the system and help you fine-tune it.
Learn whatever you can during this process. Ask questions about everything that is not trivial.  This will be money well spent.

Comment: IsDeleted wouldn't be the first field in the index - seems that would place the least selective field first.

Comment: @Andrew I might have got that wrong, that's why I've written `probably`. I remember reading about the correct way to order columns in a multi-column index, but I'm not sure of the most selective should be the leftmost or the least selected.

Comment: yes, it really depends on the usage and purposes, making it a difficult one to call, the query looks OLTP based not OLAP so the least selective doesn't seem the obvious first field. If there was a lot of aggregation in that query I would think different. There isn't a single right answer, its a different answer depending on the situation, a classic 'it depends'

Comment: @Andrew hence the last paragraph of my answer. We can sit around suggesting solutions all days, but none of them will be as good as an expert's view on the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of assuming an OLTP based system and not OLAP, my first pass would be an NC Index - given isDeleted is likely to have the least selectivity, I would place it last, first pass would be an NC index `ReferencedxyzType, ReferencedxxxId, IsDeleted`

I might even be tempted in a higher volume scenario to move the IsDeleted out of the index onto an include instead, since it provides so little selectivity to the index itself.

There is clearly already a clustered index in place on the table (from the query plan we can see it), we don't have the details of what is in it.

The question around clustered vs non-clustered is more complex and requires a lot more knowledge of the system and usage.