# SQL Select Distinct Query Optimization Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which I know is highly unoptimized. It does the job but it's highly time consuming and unoptimized

```
select distinct w.packageid, e.OrgPackageEmailId
from epnunitsettings u,
wippackages w,
epnuser2unit n,
EpnOrgPackageEmails e,
aspnet_users r,
epnorgsettings g,
epnpackages k 
where u.SendPackageEmail = 'true'
and w.unitid = u.unitid
and n.unitid = u.unitid
and e.unitid = u.unitid
and e.userid = r.userid
and e.disabled = 'false'
and g.orgid = e.orgid
and not exists (select 1 from WipPackageEmails
where packageid = w.packageid
and OrgPackageEmailId = e.orgpackageemailid)
and g.orgid in (3163,3261)
and g.SendPackageEmail = 'true'
and w.packageid = k.wippackageid
and k.status < 10000
```

Comment: Don't use a comma to connect tables. try to use `join`

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
  
 [**How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Using [Query analyzer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216945(v=sql.80).aspx) You add one table each time and check performance. And when you get something slow, check for proper index.

Comment: I'd convert this to ANSI joins first and foremost

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone has commented, a performance problem can be best answered if the following information are provided at the very minimum:

1. Size of the underlying tables
2. Index details in the underlying tables
3. Execution Plan screenshot

Without these details, I will try to provide some very generic suggestions that you can try out:

1. Please re-write the query using ANSI JOINS and thereby provide the
   required filter of the joins as early as possible to help SQL Server
   guide towards a better plan by avoiding unnecessary rows of the
   tables as early as possible.
2. Please try to make sure that all the columns used for 'searching'
   and 'sorting' (joined columns, where clause and searched columns,
   group by, order by, distinct) in the query are keys of some useful
   index which can be used by the query. I would suggest   creating
   composite nonclustered indexes which has all the required keys from
   the table to cover the joins and searches done in a table rather
   than creating separate nonclustered index on each field. Because
   more nonclustered index you have, the more       number of jumps to
   separate data pages SQL Server will have to make to get what it
   needs and that is going to be slower than finding all the fields it
   needs together.
3. Remember that SQL Server can make use of one index of a table for
   joining to an another table (unless it has to do Key or RID lookup
   from a nonclustered index to go find the other required columns used
   in the join/select/search in a clustered index). Hence, be smart
   while coming up with your index strategy regarding this and make
   sure you have a composite index to cover this. Only then you would
   be able to see 'index seek' in your execution plan rather than lot
   many 'index scans' and 'Lookups'.
4. Please make sure that your joined columns from different tables are
   of same datatype to avoid implicit conversion which is very
   expensive. Same is true with normal searches. If they are not, you
   can go with some suggestions provided in my comment here:
   [Why "IN " query tag is so costly in sql stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582008/why-in-query-tag-is-so-costly-in-sql-stored-procedures/56583225#56583225)
5. As explained in the above link, if your joined datatypes are not
   same, then while having to use CONVERT() function in your joining
   conditions / searches to avoid implicit conversion, you should
   consider creating columnstore index than rowstore index to make sure
   that the query can leverage an index for that column properly.
6. Even after having proper indexes, if you still do not see the
   indexes being properly used in your execution plan, it is certain
   that your statistics are not updated for sometime in the tables.
   In that case, please update the statistics in those tables immediately.

Comment: @codeDonkey please let me know f it helped. Could you please upvote the answer if it helped?